# PHP date format conversion fault in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I use wordpress as my platform, and I add a additional database for customize, when I use a query from that database and conversion a data format, the wordpress echo fault: `Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in D:\www\forums\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 249`, how to solve?

```
<?php
...
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resultset))
{
$date = date('Y/m/d g:i A',$result['date']);//line 249
...
?>
<div class="date"><?=$date;?></date>
...
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What does `$result["date"]` contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resultset))
{
    $date = date('Y/m/d g:i A',strtotime($result['date']));//line 249
...
```

Try wrapping your result date in strtotime()

Comment: Thaxs to all, but add strtotime is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
...
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resultset))
{
if($result['date']){$date = date('Y/m/d g:i A',$result['date']);}else{$date="empty";}
...
?>
<div class="date"><?=$date;?></date>
...
<?php
}
?>
```

maybe its just sometimes null!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will be able to modify the query to return a UNIX_TIMESTAMP..

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS `timestamp` ...
```

then you will be able to pass the timestamp to the date() function normally.